# how to delete image or file in local storage using react axios and node js fs.unlinkSync

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

is there an example script calling nodejs fs.unlinkSync on reactjs (I use axios)? 
I'm very confused about that

I want to delete the file / image stored in the folder using the url address. thank you

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    confirm({
      title: i18n('common.areYouSure'),
      okText: i18n('common.yes'),
      okType: 'danger',
      cancelText: i18n('common.no'),
      onOk: () => {
        resolve(true)

        // here I want to call fs.unlinkSync 


        this.handleRemove(file.file.uid); //this success handle remove preview but not actually remove file / image


      },
      onCancel: () => {
        resolve(false)
        reject(true)
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Try the fs-extra lib https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/HEAD/docs/remove.md

Comment: I mean just want to delete the file / image from the frontend (react). how do you use fs-extra on the frontend side?

Comment: How do i call this script in frontend side?                                    var fs = require('fs');
try{
 var sourceUrls = "/sampleFolder/sampleFile.txt";
 fs.unlinkSync(sourceUrls);
}catch(err){
 console.log(err);
}